# Armazenar array no banco de dados e recuperar usando uma das informações do array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, array

Preciso desenvolver um sistema onde eu capture os dados selecionados de um `checkbox` e insira tudo em uma `array`, acredito que esse seja o método mais apropriado para armazenar, e em seguida envie para o banco de dados, e na hora de recuperar os dados do banco de dados gostaria de simplesmente pesquisar por um dos valores do array.

Por exemplo tenho 3 combobox, um escrito pergunta 1, pergunta 2 e pergunta 3, se eu selecionar apenas pergunta 1 e 2, isso seria gravado no banco de dados, e na hora de recuperar o resultado via SELECT eu apenas colocasse `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE pergunta='pergunta1'`, e isso retornasse o resultado em que pergunta 1 está dentro do array armazenado

Comment: Olá bem vindo ao SOpt, de uma olha em [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como postar uma pergunta, se puder; adicione mais informações, código caso já tenha tentado alguma coisa, para a comunidade poder ajudar e não fazer por você, boa sorte.

Comment: Irmão da para fazer, não é difícil, mas é legal vc editar sua pergunta e colocar um código inicial que esteja tentando... E perguntar sobre um ponto específico... por que do jeito que tá, alguém terá de montar o script inteiro...http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Não que seja essa seja a forma correta, mas a fim de ajudar a resolver esse problema rápido e esperar que em um futuro você possa melhorar isso, sugiro que, recupere seu `array` vindo do formulário e o transforme em `json` antes de enviar no banco de dados ou mesmo, use a função `implode(',', $seu_array)` do PHP para transformar seu `array` em uma `string` separada por `,`. Ambas as formas o valor estará salvo no banco de dados como uma `string` podendo procurar usando o `LIKE '%$pergunta'`. Como eu falei, é uma solução rápida, num futuro isso vai complicar sua vida se precisar de relatórios.